# Some conflicts in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I got finished JS file that I need to integrate to Drupal theme, but there is some conflicts or something so it looks like that some parts of the script doesn't work at all. Script works without problems on HTML theme.

There is the whole script:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Navigation ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
//Add class to inernal and external links
$('.navbar-nav a').each(function(index, element) {
    if($(element).attr("href").match("^#"))
    {
        //Add class to inernal links
        $(element).addClass("internal");
    }
    else
    {
        //Add class to external links
        $(element).addClass("external");
    }
});

var lastId,
    topMenu = $(".navbar-nav"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight(),
    // All list items without external links
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a").not(".external"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
        var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
        if (item.length) {
            return item;
        }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("dropdown-toggle")) {
        var href = $(this).attr("href"),
            offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 1;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, 1450,  'easeInOutQuart');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
            return this;
    });
    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id;
        // Set/remove active class
        menuItems
            .parent().removeClass("active")
            .end().filter("[href=#" + id + "]").parent().addClass("active");
    }
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Home part - 100% hight ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
jQuery.fn.refresh = function() {
    var s = skrollr.get();

    if (s) {
        s.refresh(this);
    }
    return this;
};

function fullHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#home, .tp-banner-container').css('height', windowHeight).refresh();
};
fullHeight();
$(window).resize(function() {
    fullHeight();
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- H2 big shadow ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$("h2").each(function () {
    var h2 = $(this);
    var span = h2.parent().find("span.title-shadow");
    span.append(h2.html());
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Back to top ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$(".logo").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "easeInOutQuart");
  return false;
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Contact form ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
(function(e) {
    function n(e, n) {
        this.$form = e;
        this.indexes = {};
        this.options = t;
        for (var r in n) {
            if (this.$form.find("#" + r).length && typeof n[r] == "function") {
                this.indexes[r] = n[r]
            } else {
                this.options[r] = n[r]
            }
        }
        this.init()
    }
    var t = {
        _error_class: "error",
        _onValidateFail: function() {}
    };
    n.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            var e = this;
            e.$form.on("submit", function(t) {
                e.process();
                if (e.hasErrors()) {
                    e.options._onValidateFail();
                    t.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false
                }
                return true
            })
        },
        notEmpty: function(e) {
            return e != "" ? true : false
        },
        isEmail: function(e) {
            return /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(e)
        },
        isUrl: function(e) {
            var t = new RegExp("(^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|(www\\.)?))[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)+([\\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&;/~+#-])?", "gim");

            return t.test(e)
        },
        elClass: "",
        setClass: function(e) {
            this.elClass = e
        },
        process: function() {
            this._errors = {};
            for (var t in this.indexes) {
                this.$el = this.$form.find("#" + t);
                if (this.$el.length) {
                    var n = e.proxy(this.indexes[t], this, e.trim(this.$el.val()))();
                    if (this.elClass) {
                        this.elClass.toggleClass(this.options._error_class, !n);
                        this.elClass = ""
                    } else {
                        this.$el.toggleClass(this.options._error_class, !n)
                    }
                    if (!n) {
                        this._errors[t] = n
                    }
                }
                this.$el = null
            }
        },
        _errors: {},
        hasErrors: function() {
            return !e.isEmptyObject(this._errors)
        }
    };
    e.fn.isValid = function(t) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var r = e(this);
            if (!e.data(r, "is_valid")) {
                e.data(r, "is_valid", new n(r, t))
            }
        })
    }
})(jQuery)


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Ajax contact form ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$('#forms').isValid({
    'name': function(data) {
        this.setClass(this.$el.parent());
        return this.notEmpty(data);
    },
    'email': function(data) {
        this.setClass(this.$el.parent());
        return this.isEmail(data);
    },
    'subject': function(data) {
        this.setClass(this.$el.parent());
        return this.notEmpty(data);
    },
    'message': function(data) {
        this.setClass(this.$el.parent());
        return this.notEmpty(data);
    }
}).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        'url': $(this).attr('action'),
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'html',
        'data': $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(response) {
        $this.find('.notification').show();
        $this.find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea').val('');
    });
    return false;
});

$('.notification').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide();
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Sticky navigation ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$("#navigation").sticky({
    topSpacing: 0,
    className: 'sticky',
    wrapperClassName: 'main-menu-wrapper'
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Wow Scroll Animate ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
wow = new WOW({
    boxClass: 'wow',
    animateClass: 'animated',
    offset: 100,
    movile: true

});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Skrollr and Wow init ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

    //Skrollr
    var s = skrollr.init({
        edgeStrategy: 'set',
        forceHeight: true,
        smoothScrolling: true,
        easing: {
            wtf: Math.random,
            inverted: function(p) {
                return 1 - p;
            }
        }
    });
    //Wow init
    wow.init();
}


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Charts, Skils ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$('.chart').waypoint(function() {
    $(this).easyPieChart({
        animate: 1000,
        size: 200,
        lineWidth: 5,
        trackColor: "#fff",
        barColor:"#de3926",
        scaleColor: false,
        size: 200,
        onStep: function(from, to, percent) {
            jQuery(this.el).find('.percent').text(Math.round(percent));
        }
    });
}, {
    triggerOnce: true,
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Our work ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    App.gridOption1();


    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Ajax our team ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    $('.ajax-popup-team').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        showCloseBtn: true,
        modal: true,
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        overflowY: 'scroll'
    });


    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Ajax portfolio page ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    $('.ajax-popup-portfolio').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        showCloseBtn: true,
        modal: true,
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        gallery: {
           enabled: true,
           arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="portfolio mfp-arrow mfp-arrow-%dir%"></button>'
        }
    });


    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Portfolio gallery ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    $('.gallery-item-content').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
        $(this).magnificPopup({
            delegate: '.gallery-item', // the selector for gallery item
            type: 'image',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
    });

    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Video ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: true,
        fixedContentPos: true
    });


    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Owl carousel ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    $("#carousel-our-testimonials").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        stopOnHover: true,
        navigation: false,
        paginationSpeed: 1000,
        goToFirstSpeed: 2000,
        singleItem: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        transitionStyle: "fade"
    });
    $("#carousel-our-clients").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 10000,
        stopOnHover: true,
        navigation: true,
        paginationSpeed: 1000,
        goToFirstSpeed: 3500,
        singleItem: false,
        autoHeight: true,
        transitionStyle: "fade",
        navigationText: [
        "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
        "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
        ]
    }); 
    $("#blog-single").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
        pagination: false,
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        navigationText: [
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
            "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
        ],
        singleItem: true
    });

    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Dropdown Menu Fade  ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    $(".dropdown").hover(
        function() {            
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn(275);
            $(this).addClass("open");
        },
        function() {            
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut(275);
            $(this).removeClass("open");
    });


    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    /* -------------------------------------- Placeholder fix for IE  ------------------------------------------ */
    /*********************************************************************************************************/
    (function($) {       
        if (!Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
            $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                    input.removeClass('placeholder');
                }
            }).blur(function() {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.addClass('placeholder');
                    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                }
            }).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
                $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                        input.val('');
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    })

});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Count  ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$('#statistic').waypoint(function() {
    $('.timer').countTo();
}, {
    triggerOnce: true,
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Show and hide color-switcher  ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$(".color-switcher .switcher-button").click(function(){
    $( ".color-switcher" ).toggleClass("show-color-switcher", "hide-color-switcher", 800);
}); 


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Color Skins  ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$('a.color').click(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#style-colors').attr('href', 'css/color-schemes/' + title + '.css');
    return false;
});


/*********************************************************************************************************/
/* -------------------------------------- Loader  ------------------------------------------ */
/*********************************************************************************************************/
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").delay(450).fadeOut(800);
    $(".preload-gif").addClass('fadeOut');

});

});
})(jQuery);
```

I hope someone can help me find possible conflicts and resolve it.

### Update

I looked at console and found an error, so I commented out 'App.gridOption1();' from script and looks like everything is ok. Right now I'm facing an error from console but from some other script. Here is that script:

```
$.scrollTo = $.fn.scrollTo = function(x, y, options){
    if (!(this instanceof $)) return $.fn.scrollTo.apply($('html, body'), arguments);

    options = $.extend({}, {
        gap: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        animation: {
            easing: 'swing',
            duration: 600,
            complete: $.noop,
            step: $.noop
        }
    }, options);

    return this.each(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: !isNaN(Number(x)) ? x : $(y).offset().left + options.gap.x,
            scrollTop: !isNaN(Number(y)) ? y : $(y).offset().top + options.gap.y
        }, options.animation);
    });
};
```

The error I got is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.fn')
    (anonymous function)
```

That is the first line in this script. I think that this error is related with some part of the script that I published first. There is a part 'Home part - 100% hight' that is related to this.

Any suggestion?

Comment: "there is some conflicts or something" is __not__ useful information. Are you getting any errors when you open the console? What parts of the code are not working?

Comment: @Andy I looked at console and updated my question...

Comment: Wrap the code from your update in `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` @mixerowsky

Answer (score 1):

$.fn is usually used for a jquery module/extension. Make sure that jquery is loading before the scrollto code.
You might also want to look at using [drupal behaviors and properly integrating js in drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722)